# how to pass js variables to jinja2

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I want to pass a javascript variable into jinja2 url_for construct. But it only seems to read plain strings and not variables. Can this even be done? My script is in the HTML file. In the code below I want the name argument to be equal to variable text but it just doesn't parse it.

```
<script>
    function process_search_submit() {
        if (chosenId === "") {
            alert("Please choose a category");
        } else {
            var text = $("#media_name").val();
            if (text === "") {
                alert("Please enter a name of anime/manga/book you want to search");
            } else {
                var category = chosenId;
                if (category === "anime") {
                    $('#query_form').attr("action", "{{url_for('anime', name=text)}}");
                } else if (category === "manga") {
                    $('#query_form').attr("action", `{{url_for('manga', name=text)}}`);
                }
               
                $('#query_form').submit();

            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

**UPDATE, from views.py**

```
@app.route("/anime", methods=["POST"]) 
def anime():     
  name = request.args["name"]
```

I just want to have `/anime/{user typed name of anime}` or `/anime?name={user typed name of anime}` anime in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.  Add these to you template to diagnose:

```
{{ text }}
{{ url_for('anime', name=text) }}
```

And see what is actually inserted into the template.  S

Your view should be something like:

```
@app.route("/anime/<text>", methods=["GET", "POST"]) 
    def anime(text=""):     
      return render_template('hello.html', text=text)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It just shows it like this: `$('#query_form').attr("action", "/anime/");` in the sources of the page.

Comment: So, show how you are passing the variable `text` to the template.

Comment: I am trying to pass it like that:
`{{text}}
$('#query_form').attr("action", "{{url_for('anime', name=text)}}");`
I've tried passing like `$('#query_form').attr("action", "{{url_for('anime', name={{text}})}}");` but it gives the throws an error in flask.

Comment: `@app.route("/anime", methods=["POST"])
def anime():
    name = request.args["name"];`

I just want to have /anime/{user typed name of anime} or /anime?name={user typed name of anime} anime in the URL.

Comment: See update to your question and my answer.  You need to show the `render_template()`